# Not able to combine all css files with bundle.css with webpack like bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

**I am trying to combine my css files to bundle.css through webpack in reactjs , I am able to add all JS file in bundle.js but not able to combine all css file to bundle.css.
There is src directory which contain all componet(js files) code. and there is public directory which contain all css files.
Can anybody help how to mange this**

My webpack.config.js is

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('babel-polyfill');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
// for js
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'); 
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
// for html 
var PUBLIC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');  
// for css
var CSS_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/css');
var CSS_BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/css'); 

var combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
  entry: {
   'js':['babel-polyfill',APP_DIR + '/app.js'],
   //'html': PUBLIC_DIR+'/index.html',
   'css' : [
      CSS_DIR +'/bootstrap.min.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/appointment.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/menu.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/default.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/style.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/react-datepicker.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/react-day-picker.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/notifications.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/react-intl-tel-input.css',
      CSS_DIR +'/slicknav.min.css'
   ]
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: CSS_BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.css',
  },
  plugins: [
    //new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('local')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test : /\.js?/,
      include : APP_DIR,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader : 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true
      },
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-object-assign']
      }
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg)$/, 
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' 
      },
      {
          test: /\.css?$/,
          loader: 'style!css' // This are the loaders
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          combineLoaders([{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true
            },
            query: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }])
        )
      }]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

index.html

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>My APP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <!--Stylesheet-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/appointment.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/react-datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/react-day-picker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/notifications.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/react-intl-tel-input.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slicknav.min.css"/>
        //<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css"/>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxf2BKbwAcqylDnCKWFuV8q3qlS5tNtcI&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
    </head>
        <body class="home">   
            <div id="root"></div>
            <!--Bundled file-->
            <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you share what error you are getting

Comment: ERROR in multi css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /home/bhuvnesh-kumar/Bhuvnesh/Sourcefuse/droppoint/consumer_webapp
 @ multi css

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Webpack does not support multiple output.
So in your `webpack.config.js` file include only `js` file paths.

```
output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

Now for your `css` files, do not include that in your `html` file instead include it in your entry file `app.js`

For example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import RoutesComponent from './routes';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

//import all your css files here only
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './public/css/menu.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <RoutesComponent/>
                    </BrowserRouter>

        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: tried the same but now getting following error

if(element.loader) return element.loader.split("!");
                                          ^
TypeError: element.loader.split is not a function

Then i look for resolving this error and tried all possible cases but still not able to figure out

Comment: During debugging find out that this issue somehow related to importing of css files in app.js.
Since when i commented those files Webpack build successfully

Comment: once try installing `style-loader` and include it in the `webpack.config.js`

Comment: in your `webpack.config.js` replace your previous css loader configuration with this `{ test: /\.css$/,use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']}`